# IC that would pull output to the ground, perhaps NOT gate?

Tags: digital-logic

I have a board with four relays on it. It has a standard Vcc, Gnd, and In1-In4 pins. I want to control it with Arduino or in my case an ESP32. However, I noticed that when output pin on my controller is pulled HIGH nothing happens when it's pulled LOW the relay will engage.

This is a problem when the board is reset because of all the relay switches will engage until and this isn't something I want. After some digging, I made this:

[image: Simple inverter]

This works as desired, there's always 5V on the relay and the relay is disengaged all the time. When I output a signal to the base of the Q1 it will pull the output to the ground and the relay will engage.

Right now I have four of these relays and pretty soon I'll have more. So, I'd like to solve this with an IC. In particular, I was looking at the IC7404 which is a bunch of NOT gates, however, I am not sure this will solve my problem.

So, is there an IC that would pull the output to the ground when the signal is present on the input? Will 7404 work and I'm just not seeing something? :)

Edit: [This is the relay module I am using](https://www.banggood.com/5V-4-Channel-Relay-Module-For-Arduino-PIC-ARM-DSP-AVR-MSP430-Blue-p-87987.html). I wasn't able to find any useful data sheets on it.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. I'm going to go right ahead and awad you a +1 for your schematic. It's probably solvable with an inverter, but to answer that we need you know your output power requirements. Do you know how much load you have?

Comment: You might want to add a reverse biased diode from Output to 5 V if you're operating a relay. Googling flyback diode or freewheeling diode will give more information

Comment: Please provide a link to the datasheet for the relays. We need to know how much current they require. A 7404 is probably not going to be able to sink enough current.

Comment: What do you mean signal is present?  Is it a high voltage +5v at "input" node and what is "signal not present", 0V or unknown/disconnected?

Comment: It's not clear *why* the relays would be active at reset, as normally pins are in a high impedance state unless you unwisely chose mode strapping pins or those involved in a bootloader.

Comment: @R.Joshi if set an output pin on Arduino to HIGH the relay won't engage. If I set the pin to LOW the relay will engage. The same thing happens if I ground the input pin of the relay.

Comment: @ChrisStratton When the board boots all the pins are set to LOW and that actually engages the relay and I don't want that. When setup() executes I pull the pins HIGH and the relay disengages.

TBH, I think that the pins aren't even set to LOW during the boot but are in some sort of floating state.

Comment: Yes, normally on boot pins are in a high impedance (what you called "floating") state.  That should not activate the relay.  What you really have is a software bug in configuring the port in the wrong order - set the data register bit high before you configure the pin as an output.

Comment: Maybe adding a pull-up resistor on base would solve your issue.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Just setting pins to high right away is good enough. Setting them before they are marked as output simply feels wrong.

I am glad that I won't have to deal with transistors and added complexity of the circuit and I am also glad that I figured out and learned something new. :)

Comment: @BigWhale - what is "wrong" is waiting until the pins are outputs to set them to safe levels.  Presetting the output data registers *before* enabling the drivers is the correct solution - this is about facts, not feelings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that relays are actuating at reset when pins should be in a high impedance mode is worrisome, and something that you need to fully understand in order to validate your system and fix it.

Edit: now that it is clear that this is a **software bug** in your code, to solve the inadvertent drive low during starting, configure the pin's output data register bit to high *before* you set the pin to be an output.

That said, a literal answer to your original question would be a chip containing several `open collector inverters`.

The 74xx05 is an example.

The 74xx06 is similar but allows applying acceptable voltage to the output even when this exceeds the supply voltage, for example you can operate the part on 3.3v but pull down outputs from 5v.

But these are not the solution to your *actual* problem.

Comment: You were right, I had to check my startup procedures. I usually set all the I/O parameters and initialize everything then I take care of the default state of the pins. When setting the pin as an output pin it goes automatically in the LOW state. It appears that there was enough time between pinMode() and the first digitalWrite() that set the pin to a HIGH state, preventing the relay to engage. So my solution is now to call pinMode() and then immediately set the pin to HIGH.

Comment: Set it to high *before* you make it an output, not after.

Comment: You have a driver for the relay coilm,  yes? Add pullup resistors to their inputs, be done with it.

Comment: @CrossRoads pull-up resistors will neither solve the problem nor marginally improve things at all.  The problem is that the asker's software is doing things in the wrong order, driving the pin low before it drives it high.  The mistaken driving low would overcome your pull-up resistor.  And besides, these are probably the cathodes of optocoupler LEDs - a pull-up won't actually do anything there at all, what is needed is not erroneously completing a path to ground.

Comment: The pullups would keep the pins high while the device goes thru reset/boot process and the pins are floating.

Comment: No.  Again, that is not the issue.  The issue is that **the software is actively driving the pins low** before it drives them high.  Pull up resistors can't fix that.   And with the type of relay drivers seemingly being used, floating during reset would not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to swap the connections of the NO and NC pins of the relay.

The next option is to invert the programming logic for that pin. You can add a few constants

```
#define RELAY_ON LOW
#define RELAY_OFF HIGH
```

To bias the relays into a certain state during reset (while the output pin is high impedance) you can add a pull-up or pull-down resistor as needed. The IO pin will easily overpower the current leaked through the resistor and still properly switch the relay.

Using those 2 techniques you can pick the default state of the relay to be the unpowered state. Either because it's the one used most of the time or because it's the fail-safe option.

Comment: I think you missed the point. The OP doesn't want the relays to be activated **at reset**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ["User manual"](http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-output-devices/5-volt-4-channel-arduino-relay-module-user-manual/) for your relay.
You should really never design a system without having all datasheets first.

From the schematic supplied there it can be clearly seen you can just connect your controller **directly** to the InX pins. That is, none of the schematic you devised is  needed.

Since the input of the optocouplers is able to operate in [open-collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector) mode I would suggest to you to just keep the corresponding pins of your uC as **input/High-Z** when you want to keep the relays at NC.

Since I'm not familiar with your controller, here is some pseudo-code to help you:

Initialization, for each pin controlling a relay:

```
Set direction to input
Set level to "0" (do NOT change direction to output)
```

Command relay to NO:

```
Set direction to output
```

Command relay back to NC:

```
Set direction to input
```

Usually a uC will wake up with its pins already as input, so the first line of the initialization is redundant, but it's always safer to perform it to make sure the system is at a known state.
Make sure you do not have some code that does a general init of all pins to some values as part of some boiler-plate code, beginners are known to make this mistake.

P.S.
For the time when you **actually** will need some inverting current driver just use something like a [ULN2003A](http://www.ti.com/product/ULN2003A)!

Comment: "a ULN" is not a part.  Show the actual part number, don't hide it in the link

Comment: This is the only part of that series that I've ever used, so it's always been "just a ULN" for me.